# Need to process all records in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I've designed a software to store news from hundreds of news agencies in the world. I also have created a URL to access them from my application like this:
http://www.myweb.com/news/health/1234567
Now I want to change this format to something else but I need to create a redirect module which handles old URL requests from users that are coming from Google, so I need to read millions of records and convert them.
As far as I know it's not possible to read all records of a table in Cassandra. what should I do for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing ALTER TABLE will not work for you in this case?

The DataStax Java driver 2.0 provides automatic result set pagination.
I'd probably read all rows a batch at a time and write out the changes to a new table and then drop the old table. Probably a job for the weekend or evening.

"Allows you to iterate indefinitely over the ResultSet, having the rows fetched block by block until the rows available on the client side are exhausted. This makes it easier to manipulate large result sets while also shielding the client application from instatianting an accidentally large ResultSet object."

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.0/java-driver/whatsNew2.html

Example CQL here:

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/client-side-improvements-in-cassandra-2-0

For the Astyanax driver:

https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/AllRowsReader-All-rows-query

Cheers,